# DataContext and DataBinding

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, datacontext

I just started working on `Silverlight` and reading several code examples and following them. However, there is this one concept that I am finding difficult to grasp and Its the `DataBinding` concept,the use of `this.Content` for navigating to pages etc. So I came here to request if you guys can refer to a good `resource` for a beginner like me.

**NOTE** If someone could explain the concept here with examples, I'll really appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

read below links

[DataContext](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/)

vs

[DataBinding](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)

In a single line:

**DataContext mean the datalayer in WPF. When you define the DataContext(every control has this property) you give it access to an instance of a class. And then that control would be able to bind it's properties to the properties of DataContext class.**

There is much more to databinding but just to make it work this is a very bsic you need to understand.

also have a look at architecture of WPF:

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750441(v=vs.100).aspx)

&

[WPF layers](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wpf/8F8J021013-Understanding-WPF-Architecture.html)